# Which tool is capable to create avi with multiple audio tracks?

Tags: video, audio, encoding

What tool may be used for creation of videos (e.g. AVI containers) with multiple audio tracks?

I mean the tracks which may be switched independently, like different languages on a DVD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), a free command line tool, can do it.

A syntax example can be provided if you describe your workflow.

Comment: anything with a GUI maybe?

Comment: Any GUI that can do this will just be running ffmpeg under the hood. I don't use one, but I believe [WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/) or [myffmpeg](http://www.myffmpeg.com/) should work.